# Override method in abstract parent with parameters in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, types, overriding, type-erasure

Basically I want to debug a method that is implemented in an abstract parent class but as Eclipse does not allow this (All I get is a message it can't find the file) what I usually do is to override the abstract parent method in the specific child and just copy pasting the code to see what's going wrong (in case it does). I was working with C# for 6 years and only recently switched to Java but couldn't find an answer on how to debug into an abstract class (which frankly, should definitely be possible) so if there is a proper way to handle this, please let me know.

I have an abstract parent class with many parameters:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends BasicParameterClass, ... many other basic params> {
    public void myMethod(AnInterface<T, ... all the other params> arg) {
        ...
        // implementation
        ...
    }
}
```

The specific class is this:

```
public class MySpecificClass extends MyAbstractClass<SpecificParameterClass, ... many other specific params> {
    @Override
    public void myMethod(AnInterface<SpecificParameterClass, ... all the other specific params> arg) {
        ...
        // implementation
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course I cannot override this, but removing the override won't work either because, hooray, type erasure. So, how am I supposed to override this method?

Comment: I don't really understand your situtation, but there's nothing special about abstract classes, generics and debugging. You can certainly step into a method in an abstract class. If Eclipse is crapping out, then it's an Eclipse problem. Risking to be _that guy_: try IntelliJ or seek how to fix Eclipse.

Comment: @kaqqao I know it's an Eclipse problem but I can't simply switch.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was under the impression you think this is a general Java problem (because there was no Eclipse tag). I added the tag now to make it clear.